# Server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete, but successul using WAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-applications

When I try to open my login page, it shows an error like '" the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete" ...I think the issue might be with .htaccess

Below is the .htaccess:

Turn on URL rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
Installation directory
RewriteBase

// Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

// Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL


RewriteRule .*/ index.php/$0 [PT,L] "
```

Am not that sound in coding stuffs..could anybody help me with it..btw i have successfully test this project on my system using wamp server..but when am trying it on webserver getting redirect loop error!!...its an open source project for blood donor database please help me with it?.. am giving a link for all the related files for downloading...please download and check whats wrong with it..thanks in advance ....

link:   http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1351767344

Comment: 'Im no expert at this but these <BR>'s are very suspicious.

Comment: And the fact the comments aren't commented, and there is a stay quote at the end. Can you copy/paste the EXACT htaccess then if gives more confidence that what we're reading is right.

Comment: <br> is not there in the coding...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by adding a / and then appending to index.php, you're looking for a folder "index.php" with a file/folder structure underneath. That won't exist. So you need to append the URL as a paramter: This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$0 [L]   # Use [NE,L] to stop the URL being escaped.
```

BUT... you may as well use the original request URL in PHP which makes htaccess much simpler and easier to understand, plus you won;t end up with dodgy characters in the URL (which is possible with the above)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

then, in PHP,

```
$originalURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This is simpler to handle, and more "correct" for handling special characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple causes for this error. Chrome has more meaningful error messages.

Possible issues with redirect rules:

- Clear all your cookies. If a cookie is corrupt, or if redirect info is stored in cookies, this could cause problems.
- Are there multiple redirect rules?
- check your htaccess rules for redirects
- do you have multiple redirect plugins installed?
- Ensure there is only 1 redirect rule for each url. Use relative url's to cover both http and https protocols.